# How to transform valid JSON to CSV?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm trying to extract information from a JSON file and write some of the contents to a CSV file.

Here is an example of my text

```
"data":{"headers":{"sender":"frank@abc.com"
"to":"jim@def.com"
"subject":"Help with this project"
"x-received-time":"14144273245408"
"received":"from abc.com ()\r\n        by mail.mail.com with SMTP (Postfix)\r\n        for jim@def.com;\r\n        Mon
"from":"\"Help with this project\" <frank@abc.com>"
"date":"Mon, 27 Oct 2014 09:03:14 -0500"
"id":"1414427328-2345855-frank"
"to":"jim@def.com"
"time":14144273245408
"subject":"Help with this project"
"fromfull":"frank@abc.com"
```

I want to grab the contents from:  to, fromfull, id, subject, date  and write it to a csv file where To is column A, fromfull is column B, and so forth.

Can anyone offer any assistance? This is a JSON response.

Comment: Your content looks like JSON. Consider looking for ways to convert JSON to CSV.

Comment: Will the data always be laid out the way you've shown it? Or did you simply do that for clarity purposes?

Comment: This is always the layout.  There is more information within the file than just this, but it will always be laid out pretty much identical to this.  Prior to this layout, I ran a SED to break everything out into multiple lines.  So if I extract the data after that SED, then the layout should always look like this.

Comment: try piping your output through json_pp, less work.

Comment: Check out [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/). This will be as simple as something like: `jq '. | @csv' myfile.json`.

Comment: All the answers are missing on the fact that JSON is unordered, so it's perfectly valid to have `[{"name":"foo", age:21}, {age:23, "name":"bar"}]` as JSON for instance. Except the Node one that is.

Comment: I added a complete answer for creating the CSV using `jq`, as mentioned by @David . My solution also deals with the key ordering issue raised by @BenjaminGruenbaum .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following perl command to create the CSV output, open a terminal and type:

```
perl -n0e '@a= $_ =~ /"date":(".*?").*?"id":(".*?").*?"to":"(.*?)".*?".*?"subject":(".*?").*?"fromfull":"(.*?)"/gs;  while (my @next_n = splice @a, 0, 5) { print join(q{,}, @next_n)."\n"}' inputfile.txt
```

It will work even if you have multiple headers in your input file.

Note that only the last "to": field is taken into account (it seems that your headers provide the info twice)

The command output:

```
"Mon, 27 Oct 2014 09:03:14 -0500","1414427328-2345855-frank",jim@def.com,"Help with this project",frank@abc.com
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I need to add a few more fields as what you posted accounts for To and FromFull, but not ID, Subject, or Date.     It looks like you are adding \"to\":\"(.*?)\".*?   to indicate a new structure, but I can't pick out the exact syntax to add additional fields.   THANK YOU so much, as I don't know PERL much at all.

Comment: As indicated in the original post:  to, fromfull, id,  subject, date

Comment: I basically just need to create a spreadsheet with basic topical information from emails.

Comment: @BeMyFriend: Sorry I missed your edit, please check the new command

Answer (score 16):

You can convert this JSON to CSV in a single line with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
jq '.data.headers | [.sender, .to, .subject, ."x-received-time", 
.received, .from, .date, .id, .to, .subject, .fromfull] 
+ [(.time | tostring)] | join(", ")'
```

Breakdown:

- `.data.headers` - Emit headers as an object

  - If data contained an array of headers it would be `.data[].headers`
- `[…string keys list…]` - Emit string values as an array
- `+ [(.time | tostring)]` - Emit time as a string and add to the array
- `join(", ")` - Join the array values using a comma and a space

  - Substitute your favorite delimiter here

### Update 2022:

jq supports `@csv` (Comma Separated Value) or `@tsv` (Tab Separated Value) formatter. The same above code can be written as:

```
jq -r '.data.headers | [.sender, .to, .subject, ."x-received-time", 
.received, .from, .date, .id, .to, .subject, .fromfull] 
+ [(.time | tostring)] | @csv'
```

Comment: You have to parse the output to `| sed 's/"//g'` to get rid of the quotes at the end

Comment: Nice tool to develop this: https://jqplay.org

Comment: jq also has a dedicated @csv filter, very nicely described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq

Comment: actualy, without the "-r" parameter, JQ will create a single cell with these values. You want to use "jq -r ... > data.csv" to output Comma Seperated values correctly. This way you can also handle newline characters "\n"

Answer (score 6):

Since you are working with JSON files, why not parse it as such? Install `nodejs-legacy` and create a NodeJS script such as:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node
// parseline.js process lines one by one
'use strict';
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    var obj = JSON.parse(line);
    // add the fields which you want to extract here:
    var fields = [
        obj.data.headers.to,
        obj.data.headers.subject,
        // etc.
    ];
    // print the fields, joined by a comma (CSV, duh.)
    // No escaping is done, so if the subject contains ',',
    // then you need additional post-processing.
    console.log(fields.join(','));
});
```

Assuming you have a valid JSON string on each line of a file:

```
node parseline.js < some.txt
```

Or if you really want to read a single file and parse fields from that:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node
// parsefile.js - fully read file and parse some data out of it
'use strict';
var filename = process.argv[1]; // first argument
var fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
// add the fields which you want to extract here:
var fields = [
    obj.data.headers.to,
    obj.data.headers.subject,
    // etc.
];
// print the fields, joined by a comma (CSV, duh.)
// No escaping is done, so if the subject contains ',',
// then you need additional post-processing.
console.log(fields.join(','));
```

Then run it with:

```
node parsefile.js yourfile.json > yourfile.csv
```

Comment: If you have a shabang in place can't you just `./parseline.js < some.txt`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes you can, but then you first need to `chmod +x parseline.js` first.

Comment: to be fair I was pointing that out as a question out of politeness, I thought it could be a good edit for your question but you might disagree, good answer nontheless.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I deliberately omitted it to avoid explaining the need to add the executable bit (which is not related to the post) and to clarify which program is responsible for it. You can of course make it executable (recommended to save typing!) or put it in `$PATH` as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jsonv [from GitHub](https://github.com/archan937/jsonv.sh)

And then the following command:

```
cat YOUR_JSON_FILEname | jsonv to,fromfull,id,subject,date > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [**awk**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/awk.1posix.html) implementation:

```
   awk -F ":" '{gsub("\"","",$1);key=$1;sub(key " ","");gsub("\\","",$0);value[key]=$0; if ("fromfull"== key) print value["from"] ";" value["to"] ";" value["fromfull"] ";" value["id"] ";" value["subject"] ";" value["date"] ;}' jsonFile > csvFile
```

This script read line until found "fromfull" line, than print `csv` line, so it should works also with multiple sequences.

This is the result:

```
  ""Help with this project" <frank@abc.com>";"jim@def.com";"frank@abc.com";"1414427328-2345855-frank";"Help with this project";"Mon, 27 Oct 2014 09 03 14 -0500"
```

Comment: This was really close and worked for the most part.  Just the perl implementation came out slightly better formatted.  Thanks though!

Comment: You are welcome. I update my answer, but @SilvainPineau solution is better, also because awk behaviour on `\\\` is strange due to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/102208).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gawk script I just whipped up for you!

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
  FS="\""
  output=""
  nodata=1
}

/^"data"/{
  if( ! nodata )
  {
    gsub("|$","",output)
    print output
    nodata=0
  }
  output=""
}

/^"[^d][^a][^t][^a]/{
  if ( $2 == "to" || $2 == "fromfull" || $2 == "id" || $2 == "subject" || $2 == "date" )
    output=output$4"|"
}

END{
  gsub("|$","",output)
  print output
}
```

It should work on a file with a bunch of like entries. If you want to add other items to the list, just add them in the if statement. I did find one problem with your data set though: the dates. They contain commas so it can't be a true CSV. Instead I just separated it with another character.